# How to install certificate on Samsung Galaxy WATCH 4/5 with Android WearOS?

Tags: android, certificate, adb, wear-os, samsung-galaxy-watch

I need to install this certificate on my Galaxy Watch, running WearOS:
https://cacerts.digicert.com/BaltimoreCyberTrustRoot.crt

I tried a lot of things via wireless ADB but I still didn't manage. Anyone of you experts there have some suggestions on how to do this?